# make appear a socialbar just during the article's content height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show the famous 'social bar' of my blog with this code but only works with the screen height

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>650 && $(this).scrollTop()<1500 ){ 

                    $('.social').show('slow');
    }else{
         $('.social').hide('slow'); 

    }
```

**'social'** is the class of the div that I want to show just while the article's content is on the screen, I need that once of posts' content is not on screen, the social bar just disappear

here are the "containers" that I use either for the article's content or the social bar 'share options'

article's content:

```
<div class="postcontent">
<p> <?php echo $content; ?></p>
</div>
```

social bar:

```
  <div class="social">
//'the bar share options'
  </div>
```

To further explain, let's suppose I have two divs, the first one has the article's content or message, the second one is the social bar. I just want to show the second one while the first one is being showed on the screen, then... when the screen top exceeds the first div's height, I want to hide the second div that I was showing previously, i mean the social bar... it's just like I need to show a share bar only while the user reads the content and after the article's content, the bar disappear I mean at the end, when there's no more content to read...

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle.

Comment: thanks dude, ok the thing with your example is that what about the article's content? if it changes? do I have to be always setting px or it will work dynamically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    $(document).scroll(function(){
vhHeight = $(window).height() / 100; //As JS cant get 100%, we'll divide viewport height into 100 units. So that we gonna calculate our distance.

//This gives our trigger point a distance from top. 10% for example. Trigger point could be any element. I made this, but it can be changed for any element in your code
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.triggShow').offset().top  - vhHeight * 10)  {
            $(".social").show();
        }
  else{
//This says "if user goes above post content, hide social again.
    $(".social").hide();
  }
//This says "If user has been finished the post content, hide social too
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.triggHide').offset().top - vhHeight * 90) {
    $(".social").hide();
  }
    });
```

I'll add this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxuoh4vq/6/) and here you will see how does trigger points work.

Comment: How does this achieve the desired goal?

Comment: This was the code used in Fiddle. Is not the same distance on px he want or need, but is the example. He just need to edit it.

Comment: What if the content grows or shrinks?

Comment: Well, that's what he asked for. Also, on FIDDLE 2, I made it with Trigger Points. So he could set those trigger points on footer or bio or wherever he wants  to, and that will be dynamic.

Comment: that's what I needed n.n

Comment: This works, but why are you using extra elements for this? Why wouldn't you just use the target element? The others are unnecessary.

Comment: Also, you havent accounted for the height properly so the element disappears before the content is off the screen, [see this screenshot](http://prntscr.com/b3tly2)

Comment: 1st.- I'm not a master on jQuery, as you could see, so, thanks for share your  code. I'll study it.

2nd.- Social Bar is hiding cause It's like "content" has some height, but it could be weird be reading last row (Of the post) and the social bar still there. So, that's why I set the percentage of vh. it can be changed for 100% or 90% or 10% of the content height.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

#### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/va9chv9r/)

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  var $trigger = $('.postcontent');
  var $target = $('.social');
  var windowPosition=$(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height();
  var targetPosition=$trigger.offset().top+$trigger.outerHeight();
  if(windowPosition>$trigger.offset().top && targetPosition>windowPosition-$(window).height()){
     $target.show();
  }
  else{
  $target.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
}
.spacer{
  height: 2000px;
}
.postcontent{
  background-color: #fff;
  
}
.social{
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Scroll down to content

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="postcontent">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex feugait percipit has, melius definiebas pro cu, eum euismod mentitum an. Vis tritani verterem inciderint ne, id meliore assentior has, legere putant vix et. At sea eius tamquam definitiones, melius impetus est te. Eos hinc volumus nominati in, ut nostro ullamcorper has. Erat appetere laboramus at ius, ubique audire necessitatibus ad est. Oratio antiopam et qui, at pri omnium ceteros.

 In omnes graeco quodsi vim. Ius habemus nusquam forensibus ad, eirmod nominati an pro, ex aliquid conclusionemque vituperatoribus his. Usu euripidis theophrastus ea. Quo hinc brute volumus te.

 Sed in laoreet omittam, vix at meis quaeque facilisi, ad dicit repudiandae vim. An vivendum scripserit eos. Ad mea veri vocent. Qui oratio malorum salutatus et, pri ex adhuc ubique putent, soleat nonumes platonem ex pri. Cu quo dicam scaevola periculis. Partem commune mentitum eu eum, ad dicit ludus eam, ei malorum molestie recteque has. Vis ad mucius corrumpit, eos cu omnis quando ignota, solet minimum platonem ne mea.

 In quodsi propriae copiosae vis, dicat nulla vivendo cum at. Lorem deserunt delicatissimi at pro. Sit eripuit numquam honestatis eu, per ex menandri expetenda contentiones, autem epicurei laboramus eos an. Nec brute ubique id. Ut tempor scripta pro.

 No eum novum inimicus. Et quidam laoreet indoctum eam. Ne facilisis incorrupte quo, sed ea elitr legimus. Eum erat iriure tincidunt ea, et est theophrastus suscipiantur. Duo causae epicurei ad, in impetus vivendum est.

 Dolor omittam intellegebat ne nam. Eos in saepe graecis adversarium, mazim exerci has ut, albucius interesset quaerendum vix id. In quidam utroque consequuntur eum, posse dolorum inermis ea vix. Usu brute eruditi consectetuer ex, in per vocent conceptam efficiendi.

 Solet euripidis consetetur ius no, prompta phaedrum pri eu. Vocent audiam antiopam et vis. Soleat tritani ei vis, duo rationibus interpretaris ea. Tractatos intellegat pri in, no duo aliquando eloquentiam, homero iisque cu quo.

 Laudem euripidis usu ea. Nulla oportere cum eu. Meis deterruisset no vim. Usu no tantas nonumes eleifend, harum minimum voluptua eum ex. Omnes doming facilisi et vel. Denique partiendo sed id.

 Nam ad meis scripta iuvaret. An sed aliquam consulatu. Eos officiis percipitur mediocritatem id, graeco perpetua intellegebat ea eos. Sed in amet alii facilisi, ut nihil gloriatur instructior sed, cu mea illum oporteat. Quo mundi malorum dissentias et, sit ea falli soluta tibique.

 Per ne commune sententiae. Mollis tamquam comprehensam nam ei, et enim qualisque has, ex facete elaboraret sit. Ne posse ponderum mea. Vel et sapientem instructior, dicta minimum vis eu, sed paulo altera salutatus cu.

 Pri ubique virtute torquatos no, in postea quodsi meliore vis. Ei mei unum simul scribentur. Mei quod dignissim ea. Vix ne dignissim intellegat. Eum propriae patrioque ea, adhuc iuvaret te nec, duo ferri debet vituperatoribus no. Ea cum scaevola similique. Ne pri tamquam quaeque voluptaria.

 Usu similique posidonium eu, vix habemus propriae voluptatum id. Omnes putent ancillae duo ut, no sit ipsum disputando, ipsum dissentias duo no. Ius adhuc iriure quaestio at, dictas deserunt sed ne, in his quod commune. Ut harum graeco vix, ex putant electram dissentiunt duo. Admodum suscipit officiis ei pri, mei ceteros intellegam efficiantur an. Quando dignissim vulputate ius ex, option expetenda aliquando mea an.

 Paulo clita senserit quo et, ad sit equidem singulis, sea duis ludus appellantur ex. At deleniti partiendo efficiendi usu. Ius nibh errem audiam no. Vero habemus appetere pri an. An ridens quaeque complectitur mei, pro ad discere recteque.

 Stet dolor feugait mel an, mei purto zril at, quot electram te nec. Cu mei mazim eirmod inimicus, oporteat repudiandae no mea, ea mel erat illum offendit. Ornatus tractatos duo ea, mollis evertitur eum ut. Quo stet error iusto eu, et ius evertitur complectitur, cu est vitae libris propriae. Mei ex tempor feugiat delenit, vel ne commodo omittantur.

 An vocent mentitum duo, sed ne tation albucius principes, vim noluisse scaevola an. Velit appetere vel ne, assum nihil ut eos, viris electram ius ea. Nam ei nostrum efficiantur. Ius virtute percipitur an. Has adhuc ceteros gloriatur id, populo oblique aliquam id pri, solum vivendum patrioque cu eum.

 Fugit principes repudiandae ut per, eos petentium consequat ei. Ea labore insolens scripserit est. Vel ad possim reformidans, qui diceret eripuit eu, nam omnium aliquid in. Quaeque consulatu mnesarchum nec cu, nam agam intellegam eu, detracto deleniti adversarium pro ea. Lorem dolore expetenda in ius, ius partem nullam gloriatur ex. Erat habeo nonumy id vim.

 Ex dicat voluptaria delicatissimi usu. Usu tempor audire docendi ex, qui porro iudico delectus in. Nec sumo pertinax vituperatoribus ut. Lorem vocibus quo in, te usu quot clita offendit, eum clita doctus deleniti ex.

 Ea nemore pertinax moderatius vis. Ludus prodesset theophrastus mel in, liber aeque suavitate cum an. Vituperata deterruisset eos ne, ius et probo deseruisse. Nam purto melius definiebas cu, ex sed nostro efficiantur. Pri at audire tibique, cum ea etiam exerci. Id ius alii semper, diam mandamus id quo.

 Tota maiorum inimicus vel eu, pri ad inani probatus sensibus, cu est alia errem voluptua. Modus repudiare sed ei, nostrum salutandi ex vix. Sit doctus virtute no. His et solum mentitum insolens, sit eius ornatus repudiare ei. Cu inciderint philosophia vis. Nostro verterem erroribus nec ea, cu tincidunt conclusionemque est, vide nostro ne vix.

 Ei vim percipit cotidieque, in recusabo pertinax quo. Vim ex percipit phaedrum sapientem, virtute forensibus no vis. Sint nonumy delectus te sea, nec ut aeterno pericula mediocritatem. Ei putant vituperata usu, cu eros prodesset his, ea eum vero facilis mnesarchum. Case abhorreant interpretaris at vix, cetero fierent cum no, usu id summo clita. Evertitur vituperatoribus vim no, et regione adipisci nec.

 Ius id augue disputando, affert platonem neglegentur vis ex, ei duo oratio utroque vivendo. Vim aliquid scriptorem at, has ut case possim. Mutat corrumpit ullamcorper pro ne, no autem etiam primis his. Iisque officiis cu vim, hendrerit quaerendum vim te. Ne atqui primis interpretaris sit, mea te iuvaret erroribus, errem posidonium ad est. Pro augue doming ut, sea ea platonem facilisis. Ex propriae atomorum molestiae sit, prima numquam commune mea an, id qui sapientem voluptatum definitiones.

 Te nam alterum.
</div>

Keep scrolling down past content

<div class="spacer"></div>
 <div class="social"></div>
```